# How to make setuptools fail if it can't find some of the files declared in MANIFEST.in?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

Had some files declared in `MANIFEST.in`, half of them were missing from the project directory. When I ran `python3 setup.py install` it has copied files that were present and gave no warning or error about the missing ones.

How to make it fail when some of the `include_package_data` files are missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only think I found is to parse output from `python setup.py dist_info`:

```
python setup.py dist_info 2>&1 >/dev/null |
    grep '^warning: no files found matching'
```

Can be used as a condition:

```
if python setup.py dist_info 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep '^warning: no files found matching'; then
    echo "Error: missing files" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```